# How do I call a function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a program that solves math equations. I want it to ask what type of question would you like to solve, then based on the answer, it then directs you to a function that I created. the function will ask you the values of some variables, and it will then solve the question.

```
What_do_you_need = raw_input("Which equation would you like to use?")

if What_do_you_need ==  "find_Y_value":
    slope = int(raw_input("Enter the slope"))
    X = int(raw_input("Enter the X coordinate"))
    Y_int = int(raw_input("Enter the Y intercept"))
    import find_Y_value

def find_Y_value(slope, X, Y_int):
    Y = (slope * X) + Y_int
    print(Y)

def find_Y_int(Y, slope, X):
    Y_int = (slope * X) - Y
    print(Y_int)

def find_X_value(Y, slope, Y_int):
    X_value = (Y-Y_int)/slope
    print(X_value)

def Slope_from_Slope_int(Y, X, Y_int):
    slope = (Y-Y_int)/X
    print(slope)

def Slope_from_Coordinates(X1, X2, Y1, Y2):
    slope1 = (Y2 - Y1)/(X2 - X1)
    print(slope1)
```

Comment: So what's the problem you need help with?

Comment: You actually already call a lot of functions, like `int`, `raw_input` and `print`...

Comment: I think what OP wants to know is how to call a specific function depending on the input of the user

Comment: This looks like a job for the [official Python 2.7 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) or [official Python 3.5 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your goal, to call the function you would replace `import find_Y_value` with:

```
find_Y_value(slope, X, Y_int)
```

and move the definitions above the place where you call them, or they will not have been defined yet.